# Correct way to handle configuration in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

I've got a project that has 10 different configuration and each configuration has about 20 different projects. Every configuration has 19 modules that builds against "Release" and the web one that points to the specific configuration so that I've the web.config filled with the propers parameters.

Is this the correct way of handling those configuration or can I have a different approach?
Thanks

Comment: If you open the Configuration Manager in Visual Studio, you will see that Release is a configuration. But you mention that your configuration have modules that build against Release? What do you mean? Do you mean that you created additional configurations based upon release or are you using configuration in another sense? Also what do you mean by module exactly?

Comment: I mean that I've modules (assemblies that won't differ between build and I build them in release profile so that when building with CI different profile those assemblies won't get re-build since they won't differ)